# Some sides of an uniformly textured cubic crate got mirrored textures. How can I fix those sides?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I've just started modelling and my first target is a cubic crate.

What I did so far:

1. modelled one side,
2. setup the UV efficiently
3. then mirror,
4. duplicate and rotate,
5. duplicate and rotate,
6. then adjusted the sides so they fit perfectly. (for some reason there was a gap)

Now I had a crate whose every side is textured the same way. (Their UV maps are overlapping)

But the texture was upside-down or mirrored (I don't remember) on the sides, so I "square/group selected" the side's uv coordinates and rotated/mirrored all of them.

But some of the sides are still backwards and I can't really fix that particular side because they are all on top of each other so I can't really select only one, only all of them.

[Here's a quick video of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HCzi.jpg)

[And here's the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P86XJQtJoMNeshlenbgtXoILNKNinYqJ/view?usp=sharing)

I guess I could select one side in *Edit Mode*, but there are like 30 vertices so this way it would take a lot of time.

Is there an efficient, better, quicker way to fix this?

Or how could I have avoided this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go back a few steps to make sure I cover everything.

- The faces of the crate didn't line up when you rotate and mirror them because the object origin is in the wrong place.

[image]

- It so happens that the origin of the crate should be at world origin, so to fix this, snap the cursor to world origin with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> then press 1. Then right click the crate face, Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.

[image]

- Continue to complete the crate as you were doing before. Note that when you mirror the crate faces, it mirrors the UV's as well.

[image]

- To fix this, select all the faces with the UV's flipped. You can do this quicker than selecting all the faces manually by pressing <kbd>L</kbd>. This selects everything that's connected under the cursor. Be in face select mode instead of vertex select mode by pressing <kbd>3</kbd> making it easier to select.

[image]

- In the UV Editor, Scale along the X axis with <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>, then enter -1.

[image]